# Stalker vs. Beaneater for Beanstalkd

Tags: ruby, beanstalkd

I'm currently using Stalker for my rails app. But I just ran into Stalker's timeout error/limit of 2 minutes. I saw [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6465581/stalker-timeout-how-do-i-change-the-timeout-settings/6618723#comment19094015_6618723) on the subject, and someone answered that Stalker doesn't implement beanstalkd's touch method, though I see that beaneater does.

So, has anyone tried beaneater and Stalker? Opinions? Which one is easier to work with vs. functionality? I'm probably going to run into the timeout error a lot for some of my tasks, and wondering if I should just increase `:ttr`, or switch to beaneater.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend you check out [backburner](http://nesquena.github.com/backburner/), we built it on beaneater and it is far more customizable and robust then stalker which is no longer well maintained. Let me know if you have any questions, backburner is well documented. (Used to use stalker before creating backburner).